# flex layout with 2 columns and 5 items

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to have a layout that has 2 columns and 5 items. I've already achieved this with widths and margins, but i'd rather build it using css flex so i can control the height of each item. Items are blog elements (image , header, portion of body) running through a foreach loop.

Because the content inside the items are flexible (i.e. it's blog items, i've set text limits, but larger words would still result in expanded height), i need the height of items 2>5 to be the same as 1.

I also need to output the same again, this time swap the layout around to give some visual difference (am using a class to alter these).

See the image below.

[image: 2 column 5 item layout]

I have a codepen set up with the following code, but can't get 4/5 underneath 2/3 - let alone accomplish the second set (6/10). https://codepen.io/grhmstwrt/pen/JjGQpmd

```css
.container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 1140px;
}

.item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  // margin-top: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
.item:nth-of-type(1), .item:nth-of-type(6){
  // flex-grow: 2.5;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px
}
.item:nth-of-type(6){
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  
  <div class="item alt">6</div>
  <div class="item alt">7</div>
  <div class="item alt">8</div>
  <div class="item alt">9</div>
  <div class="item alt">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is easier done with `display: grid;`, have you tried that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think grid is the way to go for this type of layout instead of flex.
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  
  <div class="item alt">6</div>
  <div class="item alt">7</div>
  <div class="item alt">8</div>
  <div class="item alt">9</div>
  <div class="item alt">10</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  width: 1140px;
}

.item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: auto;
  min-height: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}

.item:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

.item:nth-of-type(10) {
  grid-column: 3 / span 2;
  grid-row: 3 / span 2;
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/skeurentjes/pen/ZEQdrPN?editors=1100

Comment: Ah mate - this looks exactly like what i am looking for!